# How do I escape a String for XML?

Tags: java, fileutils

How do I escape a String for XML?

```
package test;

import java.io.File;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

public class XmlEscapeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("Demo.txt"));
        String results = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(str);
        System.out.println(results);

    }

}
```

and ***Demo.txt*** File Contains.

```
<sometext>
    Here is Demo "Lines" that I'd like to be "escaped" for XML
    & here is some Examples: on Java. Thats?good programming Language.
</sometext>
```

Comment: is there any alternative to format String  gt, lt, quot, amp, and apos ?

Comment: and i think alternative that &,'," " not good coding practice to use in Development...

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Is your file meant to contain valid XML or not? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: my file contain valid code,that program runs,, i just want to know is there any alternative like regex i.e define &, " " etc. escapeXml(str); in my java code,

Comment: Your file doesn't contain *code* at all - it contains pseudo-XML, apparently. It's not clear what you want to do with that. If you want it to be the text node in some *actual* XML, I'd strongly recommend just using an XML API.

Comment: You can e.g. find the text between tags e.g. using ">(.*?)</" regex and invoke `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(...)` on matching group.

Comment: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/xml/XmlEscapers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a *CDATA* - Block

```
<sometext><![CDATA[
    Here is Demo "Lines" that I'd like to be "escaped" for XML
    & here is some Examples: on Java. Thats?good programming Language.]]>
</sometext>
```

See here more help for this: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp.

Answer (score 1):

There are only five:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

They're easy to remember. HTML has its own set of [escape codes](http://www.escapecodes.info/) which cover a lot more characters.